# keyup not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I just realized that this piece of code works well in Firefox but not in IE 8. I need to automatically populate the list when the user enters at least 8 characters in the input field.

```
$('#inputField').keyup(function (event) { 
    var $inputField = $(this); 
        if ($inputField.val().length >= 8) { popularListBox(); } 
});

function populateListBox(){
    $.get("Default.aspx?name=test", function(data) {
        $('#listBox').children().remove();
        var options = data;
        $("#listBox").html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in your `popularList()`. Your code does not seem incorrect to me.

Comment: why are you using setTimeout?

Comment: You can check functionality availability across browsers here http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for jQuery UI autocomplete...

Comment: @Derek Still confuse why this does not work in IE.function populateListBox() 
{    
            $.get("???", function( data ) { 
                $('#listBox').children().remove(); 
                var options = data; 
 
                $("#listBox").append( options ); 
                $("#listBox").html( data ); 
 
            }); 
 
}

Comment: @user385599 - It is `populateList()`, not `populateListBox()`.

Comment: @Derek - that's just a typepo when renaming the function to protect client's information it is actually correct in my code.

Comment: @user385599 What do you want this to do? You don't appear to even have a url set for the call to `$.get`. Where is the problem? And why are you appending `data` only to turn around and overwrite it with `data`?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - My code contains an url something like this  url = 'default.aspx?name=test". I did not realize I was appending then overwritting it so I have remove the append data--guess I was more focus on getting the keypress to trigger in IE 8.

Comment: My goal is to populate the dropdown box with data relating to the data the user enter in the text field. eg. user enter product code "12345678" in input field the drop down list should contain all color relating to product "12345678" even before input field loses focus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to detect the change in input field and then do some actions, right?

I think you may detect the changes instead of keyboard actions only. For example, how about if the user paste from clipboard?

Please try these codes:

```
$('#inputField').bind('propertychange input paste', function() {
  // do poppularListBox()
});
```

It works for most input field including textarea. Please check jQuery site for more information.

In my experience, .keyup() and .keypress() often get errors in IE. I would like to use .keydown() if possible (case by case)

Comment: Thank you! Tested in FF, Chrome & IE 8.