# Asp Textbox Char Counter .on() event doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, char, counter

My ASP Code:

```
<asp:TextBox   TextMode="MultiLine" ID="TB_Comments"  runat="server" Height="79px" Width="379px" MaxLength="600"></asp:TextBox>
<span id="chars_comments">600</span> characters remaining
```

Jquery Code:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
$("#<%=TB_Comments.ClientID%>").on("keyup", function () {
    var length = $("#<%=TB_Comments.ClientID%>").val().length;
    var lenght2 = 600 - length; //Current Max Length is 600
    $("#chars_comments").text(lenght2);

});
 });
```

It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but is not working in IE.

Comment: May i know what exactly is not working ? Are you getting any error ? Event not firing ? Or element is not found ?

Comment: .on() doesn't work
Also i have tried changing the format to:
$("#<%=TB_Comments.ClientID%>").keyup(function () {
and that still works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will have to make this correction:
`$("#chars_comments").text(lenght2);` to be changed to `$("#chars_comments").text(length);`

After making this correction it was working fine for me in all browsers, even in IE(IE 9).
Please let me know with IE version, if it is not working for you even after making the correction.
JQuery version i'm using is: 1.10.2

Comment: I really Sorry, please check the Code again, i forgot to add some things =(

Comment: Hi. I checked with the modified code. It is working fine for me in IE. My IE version is IE 9. 
You probably have a different IE version.
I was able to find the below links in SO which i think are related to the issue you are facing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661678/jquery-keyup-not-working-ie-10
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360341/jquery-keyup-event-not-trigerring
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966046/keyup-not-working-in-ie-8

You can probably check these links and try to figure out, since the issue is not recreating for me.

Comment: Thanks for the information Boney. But actually i already tried with that solutions and keeps failing in IE.
Otherwise, could you tell me what JQuery version are you using?

Comment: JQuery version i'm using is: 1.10.2.
Which IE version are you using ?

Comment: jquery-3.2.0.min... Let me try with that version

Comment: What about IE version ?

Comment: weird! but it works! Thanks Boney!  
SOLUTION: I Changed the JQuery Version

Comment: Yeah it is weird.:) Glad it is working for you! I will add the JQuery version as well in the answer.